# Как получить первое значение объекта?

Tags: javascript

Как из объекта под ключом 10 получить первое найденое значение объекта, если пусто то вернуть {} ?

Заранее внутри ключи не известны

```js
let obj = {
  10: {
    20: { test: 'Test' }
    30: { test2: 'Test2' }
  }
};

let result = { test: 'Test' };
```

Comment: Используйте цикл `for (let x in obj) { obj[x] <- будет первым при первой итерации }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const result = 
  Object.keys(obj[10]).length > 0
    ? Object.entries(obj[10])[0][1]
    : {};
```

Способ довольно запутанный, потому что объекты не предназначены для использования в таком контексте. Сначала мы проверяем, что у объекта есть вложенные объекты. Если есть, вернем первый, если нет - то пустой объект. Во второй строке мы как раз получаем первый элемент. Берем массив всех пар ключ-значения, берем нулевой элемент (он представляет из себя массив из двух элементов: 0-ключ; 1-значение) и берем его значение.

Можно менее красиво, но проще:

```
let result = {};
for (let key in obj[10]) {
  result = obj[10][key];
  break;
}
```

Comment: В вопросе же сказано, что *"Заранее внутри ключи не известны"*, а у вас тут хардкод ключей...

Comment: @SwaD, ключи не известны внутри вложенного объекта, а вот ключ `10` известен